# Importance of features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-extraction, feature-construction

It is common to say in ML feature selection that features that are irrelevant in isolation can be important in combination with other features. Is there a simple example (one or two features) to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure irrelevant is the right word, but here is an example where it may not be an easy trend.

You're trying to predict blood pressure.

If you're only given weight, there may be some correlation, but someone who is 150lbs could be 5'10 or 5'4, and that would make a large difference to their overall health.

If you have both, you'll likely have a much stronger correlation to work with.

But as all things in ML you should test it yourself usingany real world examples as theory doesn't mean much if it doesn't hold true with real data.